# Tool to download contents of a webpage directory

Tags: open-source

Is there a way to download the contents of a webpage directory like [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_4_0/src/Lucene.Net/) without having to click on each folder and download each sourcefile one at a time.

Comment: Of a webpage directory you have admin access to, or someone else's?

Comment: If you are on linux, you can use wget.  But this is more of a question for http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: You can download wget for windows as well (GnuWin32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Linux/Cygwin, you could do `wget -r`, which is what I usually do to download entire websites.

If you're using Windows and don't want to install Cygwin you can try this out: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 1):

You want [Gnu wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) I think.